Multiple Vlookup in google sheets
I have BRANCH information page
TABLE;



BRANCH
WORKING DAY




WEST
4


EAST
9



And I have IDPAGE information page
TABLE;



ID
VALUE




2536
10


9865
11



There is a page named HOMEPAGE in google sheets.
TABLE;



BRANCH
ID
MULTIPLICATION




WEST
2536
40


EAST
9865
99



How can I extract values ​​from both pages using vlookup and multiply two values ​​at once in home page?
=BYROW(A2:A;LAMBDA(Y;VLOOKUP(Y;BRANCH!A2:B;2;0)))*BYROW(B2:B;LAMBDA(Z;DÜŞEYARA(Z;'IDPAGE'!A2:B;2;0)))
When I use this formula, it returns a single value but not all column values.


You may try:
=map(A2:A;B2:B;lambda(a;b;if(or(a="";b="");;index(product(vlookup({a\b};{BRANCH!A:B;IDPAGE!A:B};2;))))))



HOW SHOULD I DO IF WORKING DAY IS IN COLUMN 29 AND VALUE IS IN COLUMN 3, TO CHECK IT IN DIFFERENT FILES TOO

Share a test sheet showcasing input & expected output (entered manually)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A6SaNsgdDeCv-YvIsFIj8qJzrYp1e1VxyHWoKoTXMd4/edit?usp=sharing

formula added to Cell D2
